# Require_once not working, can't call php function

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, function, require

My project has an index.php file, and a utils.php file. I am trying to call a function in the utils.php file called dropdown. This function is going to generate a dropdown menu (I'm using Bootstrap to do that).

So, here is my index.php file:

```
<div class='container panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <!-- This is where I call the function to generate a dropdown -->
        <?php require_once('utils.php'); dropdown(); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the utils.php file, containing the dropdown() function:

```
<?php
function dropdown () {
    $str = "<form>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='sel1'><h3>Pick a Year below:</h3></label>
                    <select class='form-control' id='sel1'>
                        <option>2016</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                        <option>2013</option>
                        <option>2012</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>"

    echo $str;
}?>
```

I am doing it this way, because in the future I'll have the dropdown options to be dynamic, using a database. Thanks everyone! ;)

Comment: Anything showing up in your error log? First guess is missing semicolon after string.

Comment: syntax error, missing `;` at the end of `</form>"`

Comment: side note: echo in a function is usually a bad idea, you should use `return` then echo when you call the function

Comment: @mark.hch JESUS CHRIST!! hahahaha, That's it, omg. I've literally spent more than an hour to fix this. Thanks, guys :)

Comment: @nogad Ok nogad, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Memor-X that's it. I'm that stupid. Thank you.

Comment: if you ad error checking and disaply on, you would of fixed it in 0 seconds

Comment: @MichaelSampietro NP. Syntax issues are the worst. It's easier, though, if you either display errors while developing, or use your error log. Messages for this issue typically appear as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected [...whatever appeared instead of semicolon...], expecting ';'` or the like.